# How to find the area of this triangle? I tried to find the area of other little triangles and substract to the entire area but can't solve.

Tags: geometry, area

$MPQF$ trapezoid has MF and PQ bases,  $MF$=$24$,  $PQ$=$4$, the height of this trapezoid equals to $5$.

we have a point N on the side $MP$, such that $MN=3NP$.

find the area of the triangle $NQF$

for example $S$=$70$ (trapezoid), then I am trying to do this:
$S-S(NMF)-S(NPQ)$,  which gives me the answer, but I am struggling to find the area of $NMF$ and $NPQ$ because I don't know the heights of these triangles and can't connect those heights to trapezoid height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop a perpendicular from $P$ onto base $MF$ meeting it at the point $X.$ Then triangle $MXP$ is a right triangle with right angle at $X.$ We know $XP=5.$

Now let $\theta$ be angle $XMP$ so that $MP\sin \theta=5.$ Then since $MN=3NP$ the height of triangle $MNF$ is $15/4$ and height of triangle $NPQ$ is $5/4.$ This gives a way to finish the area calculation as you outlined.

Note I think you didn't want the letter $S$ at the start of the two smaller removed triangles.

Added. I did it as if point $X$ lies between $M$ and $C$ but think the same heights result if that is not the case, if $X$ is on the *extension* of $MF.$